# problem with special character

Tags: java, android, json, httpclient

i have a problem with a json response of an HttpPost , the resposnse contains character like & hellip; and this cause to generate an exception while creating the jsonobject or a jsonarray.

Anyone knows how decode it? i have to add an header in the request?

thanks a lot.

edit:

i already used log cat and this is the exception

```
11-02 09:17:54.472: WARN/System.err(1382): org.json.JSONException: Value XXXXXX& hellip; at authors of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at org.liquidjournal.httpProxy.ResourceManager.getAuthors(ResourceManager.java:127)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at org.liquidjournal.MyJournalGroup$PostResource.doInBackground(MyJournalGroup.java:291)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at org.liquidjournal.MyJournalGroup$PostResource.doInBackground(MyJournalGroup.java:1)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-02 09:17:54.492: WARN/System.err(1382):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

`& hellip ;` is converted directly by stack overflow

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: this is an ecoding problem, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not an encoding problem: from the error log I see, that you try to convert a `String` to a `JSONArray`. I'm not an expert in the JSON domain, but a `JSONArray` is a collection and I'd expect that you try to *add* the String (including the ellipse char) to the (existing) JSON array rather then trying to make an array *from* the String.

JSON expects all Strings to be in UTF-8 format, so it really should be able to handle the ellipse char.

Comment: you are right , i have posted the wrong log. this problem there is when i try to use the content with & hellip; as a url parameter